# Prestashop SQL Manager GROUP BY date

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I'm writing some queries for the SQL Manager in Prestashop.
I want to group by month like so:

```
SELECT AVG(total_products)
FROM ps_order_invoice
GROUP BY YEAR(delivery_date), MONTH(delivery_date)
```

But the SQL Manager refuse to save it, displaying for only message "Error".

I could not find more information about the limitation on the SQL Manager except only `SELECT` queries are accepted.
However, I can save the query if I remove the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions.

Note: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the phpmyadmin

Comment: have you tried Adding both values in the group by to the select portion of the statement? `Select avg(total_products) as ATP, YEAR(delivery_date) as yr, MONTH(delivery_date) as mo`  The engine may be complaining that you're trying to aggregate by fields not in the select.  So it doesn't know if it should average it all together since the values are not displayed or average based on year/month.  you're giving the engine mutually exclusive instructions

Comment: Yes, but it still refuse to save the query. Same problem with the query `SELECT AVG(total_products) as avg, YEAR(delivery_date) as yr
FROM ps_order_invoice
GROUP BY YEAR(delivery_date) `

Comment: is each column aliased?

Comment: what core version you use? tested in 1.6.1.1 all ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed a fresh prestashop-1.6.0.6 and was able to get your error.
After inspecting the code I found that the problem comes from the RequestSql class.

The cutAttribute method can't parse attributes like "YEAR(delivery_date)". It returns a string like "YEARdelivery_date" instead of "delivery_date".

To solve this problem you can override this class and use the cutAttribute method from the last prestashop version available.

Create a file named "RequestSql.php" located in "override/classes" with this content:

```
class RequestSql extends RequestSqlCore
{
    /**
     * Cut an attribute with or without the alias
     *
     * @param $attr
     * @param $from
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function cutAttribute($attr, $from)
    {
        $matches = array();
        if (preg_match('/((`(\()?([a-z0-9_])+`(\))?)|((\()?([a-z0-9_])+(\))?))\.((`(\()?([a-z0-9_])+`(\))?)|((\()?([a-z0-9_])+(\))?))$/i', $attr, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            $tab = explode('.', str_replace(array('`', '(', ')'), '', $matches[0][0]));
            if ($table = $this->returnNameTable($tab[0], $from)) {
                return array(
                    'table' => $table,
                    'alias' => $tab[0],
                    'attribut' => $tab[1],
                    'string' => $attr
                );
            }
        } elseif (preg_match('/((`(\()?([a-z0-9_])+`(\))?)|((\()?([a-z0-9_])+(\))?))$/i', $attr, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            $attribut = str_replace(array('`', '(', ')'), '', $matches[0][0]);
            if ($table = $this->returnNameTable(false, $from, $attr)) {
                return array(
                    'table' => $table,
                    'attribut' => $attribut,
                    'string' => $attr
                );
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And remove the file "cache/class_index.php" otherwise the override won't be find.